# How can I get an exit code from WMI spun remote process

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm executing a process remotely via WMI (Win32_Process Create) but am unable to figure out how I can determine when the process has completed executing. When I first issue the command, there is an exit code (0 for success) but that just tells me the process has been successfully spawned.

Is there a way I can know when the process ends? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Faced same issue and wrote a simple VMI wrapper:

```
var exitStatus = WmiOperations.Run("notepad.exe", wait:10);
```

Synopsis for `Run` is:

```
int Run(string command, // Required
        string commandline = null, // (default=none)
        string machine = null, // (default=local)
        string domain = null, // (default=current user domain)
        string username = null, // (default=current user login)
        string password = null, // (default=current user password)
        SecureString securePassword = null, // (default=current user password)
        double wait = double.PositiveInfinity); // (default=wait til command ends);
```

Source code can be downloaded from [here](https://gist.github.com/1739130).

*Give caesar his due, code is inspired from [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/padmanr/archive/2010/05/08/execute-a-process-on-remote-machine-wait-for-it-to-exit-and-retrieve-its-exit-code-using-wmi.aspx). Simply:*

- *Refactored things to static class*
- *Added more control on remoting parameters*
- *Redesigned event watcher to suppress the unappealing `CheckProcess` test*

Comment: Note: You may have to modify WMI security settings to allow specifyed users to run the commands (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393613%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Does this work on Windows XP/2003?  It seems from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394376(v=vs.85).aspx that ExitCode is not available on those OSs.

Comment: I'm querying for `ExitStatus` property in `Win32_ProcessStopTrace`, so, indeed, it's likely not on those OSs. Using [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) may be a reasonnable alternative depending on your needs (Actually that's what I finally used to avoid changing WMI security settings).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example create on the top of .NET objects but written in Powershell, it's easy to translate it to C#

```
Clear-Host

# Authentication object
$ConOptions = New-Object System.Management.ConnectionOptions
$ConOptions.Username = "socite\administrateur"
$ConOptions.Password = "adm"
$ConOptions.EnablePrivileges = $true
$ConOptions.Impersonation = "Impersonate"
$ConOptions.Authentication = "Default"

$scope = New-Object System.Management.ManagementScope("\\192.168.183.220\root\cimV2", $ConOptions)

$ObjectGetOptions = New-Object System.Management.ObjectGetOptions($null, [System.TimeSpan]::MaxValue, $true)

# Equivalent to local :
# $proc = [wmiclass]"\\.\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process"
$proc = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass($scope, "\\192.168.183.220\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process", $ObjectGetOptions)

# Now create the process remotly
$res = $proc.Create("cmd.exe")

# Now create an event to detect remote death
$timespan = New-Object System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
$querryString = "SELECT * From WIN32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ProcessID=$($res.ProcessID)"
$query = New-Object System.Management.WQLEventQuery ($querryString)

$watcher = New-Object System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher($scope, $query)

$b = $watcher.WaitForNextEvent()
$b
```