# Create remote process via WMI and wait for it to exit

Tags: vb.net, wmi

I'm using `System.Management` to start a process on a remote target via WMI like this:

```
...
InputParameters("CommandLine") = "executable here"
OutputParameters = ManagementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", InputParameters, Nothing)
```

This kicks off the process and my code continues to run, but I need a way of monitoring that process and not doing anything else until it finishes. Is there a simple solution? I'm hoping there's something similar to `Process.WaitForExit` like there is when creating a local process.

Comment: Please have a look to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9138255/684399).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can play with WMI events with a query like :

```
"SELECT * From WIN32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ProcessID=123"
```

Where 123 is the process ID of your process, you can then wait for next event. You'll find some sample in [Monitoring Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).